# Cypress baseUrl for different e2e folders

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I have two folders in my e2e for two different web projects. I am using cypress.config.js in the source root to define my base Urls. Problem is I need to use different URLs for each different project inside the e2e folder.

```
cypress-tests-mobile\cypress\e2e\EW

cypress-tests-mobile\cypress\e2e\FW
```

The config file looks like this :

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({   defaultCommandTimeout: 30000,    "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",   "reporterOptions": {
    "charts": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "Cypress Tests",
    "embeddedScreenshots": true,
    "inlineAssets": true   },   e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require("cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin")(on);
      const version = config.env.version || "prodFW";

      const urls = {
        prodFW: "https://www.url1.com/",
        prodEW: "https://www.url2.com/",
      };

      // choosing version from urls object
      config.baseUrl = urls[version];
```

Whenever I run the tests i just use --env version like this and it runs fine.

yarn cypress run --env version="prodEW"

First problem I have is that no matter from where I execute yarn cypress run, it always executes all tests in the e2e folder and the other project always fails since getting wrong baseUrl.
Im running it from "\cypress-tests-mobile\cypress\e2e\FW"

I was trying to solve it with different approaches

1. **making cypress.config.js for each of the projects in e2e folder**

that didnt work because whenever I open cypress, I get a message that there is no config and creates a sample cypress.config.js in my source folder.

2. **make nested list**

   const urls = {
   prod: [
   [
   prodFW: "https://www.url1.com/",
   prodEW: "https://www.url2.com/"
   ],
   ],
   };

and for each of the projects i would access the correct URL like this

```
Cypress.config("baseUrl")[0]
Cypress.config("baseUrl")[1]
```

but then upon starting i get following error

```
Your configFile at cypress.config.js set an invalid value:

Expected baseUrl to be a fully qualified URL (starting with http:// or https://).
```

I am not sure how to handle this so I would be happy for any advice.

Is it generally bad idea having two different websites in e2e?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation [Test Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Test-Configuration)

> ‼️ **Note:** The configuration values below are all writeable and **can be changed** via per test configuration. Any other configuration values are readonly and cannot be changed at run time.
>
> - baseUrl

so one option you have is to **leave `baseUrl` empty** in `cypress.config.js` and each spec file specify the correct value it needs for `baseUrl`.

```js
describe('tests for url1', {baseUrl:'https://www.url1.com/'}, () => {
  ...

or

describe('tests for url1', () => {
  Cypress('baseUrl', 'https://www.url1.com/')
  ...
```

---

Other choices are (via command line)

- [Specify the config file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-config-file-lt-configuration-file-gt)

  ```js
  cypress run --config-file cypress.config-proj-1.js
  ```
- [Specify the config item for specPattern](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-config-lt-config-gt)

  ```js
  cypress run --config specPattern=path-to-test-files-project-1
  ```

Comment: thank you for the answer, easiest solution for me is to specify the specPattern for now.

cant really define in describe blocks because I need to dynamicaly change it based on what env im executing it (i simplified the URLs in this post). Maybe if i would define all of dev/uaat/stg URLs in the descirption blocks and then just execute with --env but that seems like too much hussle. thank you for answering :)